# Comparing strings in a class file

Tags: etoolbox, strings, xstring

I am modifying a correctly functioning class file to add some capabilities. I need to compare two strings -
 a) `\@stringtextfromuser` and
 b) `ABC`.

I have loaded `etoolbox`, and `xtsring` and have tried several possibilities:

1. `\ifstrequal{\@stringtextfromuser}{ABC}{If equal}{If unequal}`.
2. `\myifstrequal{\@stringtextfromuser}{ABC}{If equal}{If unequal}`, where `\newcommand\myifstrequal{\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter}`.
3. `\IfStrEq{\@stringtextfromuser}{ABC}{If equal}{If unequal}`.
4. `\ifdefstring{\@stringtextfromuser}{ABC}{If equal}{If unequal}`.

None of these seem to be doing anything (the code inside the true cases is not getting executed when it should). I know that LaTeX is a little finicky about string comparisons, but I am sure I am missing something. It can't be this complicated.

Comment: You seem to be comparing `\@stringtextfromuser` with `ABC`, which is always going to be false. Presumably you mean to compare the expansion of `\@stringtextfromuser` with `ABC`?

Comment: Yes, I need the expansion, hence my attempts 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: `\def\@next{ABC} \ifx\@stringtextfromuser\@next …`?  Or are there special characters inside the strings?

Comment: There are no special characters anywhere. These are simple alphabetic strings.

Comment: Do you need an expandable approach? If not, the usual is simply (`\def\@tempa{ABC}\ifx\@tempa\@stringtextfromuser <stuff>\else <other stuff>\fi`.

Answer (score 3):

The example with `\IfStrEq` works, provided you have not tampered with its default setting of `\expandargs`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\userinput[1]{\def\@stringtextfromuser{#1}}

\newcommand{\decide}[3]{%
  \IfStrEq{\@stringtextfromuser}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\userinput{ABC}

\decide{ABC}{EQUAL}{UNEQUAL}

\decide{DEF}{EQUAL}{UNEQUAL}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you set `\noexpandarg` (there are good reasons for doing so), then

```
\newcommand{\decide}[3]{%
  \expandafter\IfStrEq\expandafter{\@stringtextfromuser}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
```

will do.

An almost package free solution can use `\pdfstrcmp`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\userinput[1]{\def\@stringtextfromuser{#1}}

\newcommand{\decide}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\@stringtextfromuser}{#1}=\z@ #2\else#3\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\userinput{ABC}

\decide{ABC}{EQUAL}{UNEQUAL}

\decide{DEF}{EQUAL}{UNEQUAL}
\end{document}
```

Loading `pdftexcmds` is better because so the same code will also work with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Note that `pdftex` has the primitive `\pdfstrcmp`, so in case you plan only using this engine, the package is not necessary and `\pdf@strcmp` becomes `\pdfstrcmp`.

Comment: I have not used \noexpandarg, but \IfStrEq does not work.

Comment: @user2751530 Without a minimal example it's just guesswork.